# Find the series of the function $f(x) = \cos(x)$ on the interval $[0,\pi]$

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations

> Find the sine series of the function $f(x) = \cos(x)$ on the interval $0\leq x \leq \pi$. For each $x$ in this interval, to what value does the sine series for $f(x)$ converge?

Attempted solution - The Fourier since series on $0\leq x \leq \pi$ is given by $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n \sin(nx)$$
where $$B_n = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(nx)\,dx$$
Thus for $f(x) = \cos(x)$ on $[0,\pi]$ we have 
\begin{align*}
B_n &= \frac{2}{\pi}\cos(x)\sin(nx) \,dx\\
&= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}(\sin((n-1)x) + \sin((n+1)x))\,dx \ \ \ (\text{Using trig identity }  \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) = \frac{1}{2}(\sin(\alpha - \beta) + \sin(\alpha + \beta))\\
&= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin((n+1)x)\,dx + \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin((n-1)x)\,dx\\
&= \frac{1}{\pi(n+1)}\int_0^{\pi(n+1)}\sin(u)du + \frac{1}{\pi}\sin((n-1)x)\,dx \ \ (\text{substituting} \ u = (n+1)x \ du = (n+1)\,dx)\\
&= \frac{\cos(n\pi) + 1}{n\pi + \pi} + \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin((n-1)x)dx\\
&= \frac{\cos(n\pi) + 1}{n\pi + \pi} + \frac{1}{\pi(n-1)}\int_0^{\pi(n-1)}\sin(s)ds \ \ (\text{substituting} \ s = (n-1)x \ ds = (n-1)\,dx)\\
&= \frac{\cos(n\pi) + 1}{n\pi + \pi} + \frac{\cos(n\pi) + 1}{\pi(n-1)}\\
&= \frac{2n(\cos(n\pi) + 1)}{\pi(n^2 - 1)}\\ 
&= \frac{2n((-1)^n + 1)}{\pi(n^2 - 1)}
\end{align*}
Therefore the Fourier sine series is $$\cos(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n((-1)^n + 1)}{\pi(n^2 - 1)} \sin(nx)$$

By the question's statement I believe we find the Fourier sine series for $f(x) = \cos(x)$. What I do not understand is the next question, "to what value does the sine series for $f(x)$ converge? Doesn't that depend on $n$ and $x$? I am not sure if what I did was correct any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: $$cos (n\pi)=(-1)^n $$

Comment: What the series converges to cannot depend on $n$. You have $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N.$ The value of that cannot depend on $n$ or $N;$ those are bound variables.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Ok thanks, just to check did I find the sine series of the function $f(x) = \cos(x)$ correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in fact expanding the "odd-extension" of $\cos x$.

The series converges to $\frac{1}{2}(f(x^+)+f(x^-))$.

So it converges for all $x\in [0,\pi]$.

But since there is discontinuity at $0$, and $\pi$. So it converges to $\cos x$ only for $x\in (0,\pi)$.

At $0$, and $\pi$, it converges to the mean value of the discontinuity, viz., zero.

[image]

Comment: Could you expand on your answer, or does it suffice to say that the sine series of the function $f(x) = \cos(x)$ converges to $\cos(x)$ only for $x\in (0,\pi)$?

Comment: ??? are you there

Comment: @Wolfgang-1 If what you mean by "converges" is "converges to $\cos x$", then yes, it converges only for $x \in (0,\pi)$.